# jQuery running properly in one place, but not in another

Tags: javascript, jquery

Alright, so I have the following code. The first alert runs properly upon load, but the second alert never does. To add on, clicking on the button with `id=sign` never works, but that's a separate problem. I feel the "alert" might be a clue as to where the id is going wrong, so any help will be useful. Thanks.

```
<script>
  alert("Here #1");
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#buttonClick").click(function() {
      var div = $("#mainBackground");
      div.slideUp(400, function() {
        redirect();

      });
    });
  });

  alert("Here #2");

  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#sign").click(function() {
      jQuery.ajax({
        url: "check_availability.php",
        data: 'username=' + $("#username").val(),
        'password=' + $("#password").val();
        type: "POST",
        success: function(data) {
          alert("hereagain");
          if ($("#username").val() === "") {
            //Do nothing
          } else if ($('#username').val().length < 5) {
            $("#usernameConsole").html("Username must be 5-15 characters");
            $("#username").css('backgroundColor', '#ff6666');
            $("#usernameAvailable").css('color', '#ff6666');
          } else if (data === "accept") {
            $("#usernameConsole").html("Signed In");
            $("#username").css('backgroundColor', '#66cc66');
            $("#usernameAvailable").css('color', '#66cc66');
          } else {
            $("#usernameConsole").html("Not accepted");
            $("#username").css('backgroundColor', '#ff6666');
            $("#usernameAvailable").css('color', '#ff6666');
          }
        },
        error: function() {}
      });

    });
  });
</script>

<script>
```

Comment: If the second alert isnt showing, then check your javascript console for errors, errors will halt the execution of the script

Comment: No error codes showing.

Comment: your `data:` it's wrong, should be inside of `{}` and replace the `;` at the end with a `,`

Comment: ^ thanks. However, it should be [] not {}.

Comment: So you meant the third alert, and not the actual second alert

Comment: It can be {}, but then you have to provide key-value pairs. 
{key1: value1, key2: value2}

Comment: I find it difficult to believe the Javascript console didn't report that syntax error.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed code:

```
alert("Here #1");
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#buttonClick").click(function() {
    var div = $("#mainBackground");
    div.slideUp(400, function() {
      redirect();

    });
  });
});

alert("Here #2");

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#sign").click(function() {
    jQuery.ajax({
      url: "check_availability.php",
      data: ['username=' + $("#username").val(), 'password=' + $("#password").val()],
      type: "POST",
      success: function(data) {
        alert("hereagain");
        if ($("#username").val() === "") {
          //Do nothing
        } else if ($('#username').val().length < 5) {
          $("#usernameConsole").html("Username must be 5-15 characters");
          $("#username").css('backgroundColor', '#ff6666');
          $("#usernameAvailable").css('color', '#ff6666');
        } else if (data === "accept") {
          $("#usernameConsole").html("Signed In");
          $("#username").css('backgroundColor', '#66cc66');
          $("#usernameAvailable").css('color', '#66cc66');
        } else {
          $("#usernameConsole").html("Not accepted");
          $("#username").css('backgroundColor', '#ff6666');
          $("#usernameAvailable").css('color', '#ff6666');
        }
      },
      error: function() {}
    });

  });
});
```

You were passing the data in the [ajax](/questions/tagged/ajax)function wrong.

**Edit 1:**
Preferably though, pass data as an object:

```
data: {fieldName1: value1, fieldName2: value2}
```

Comment: That worked! Thanks! Tricked me because it was happening after my alerts. Thanks.

Comment: `data:` should be an object, not an array.

Comment: You are right. It's preferable, but not a must. He was passing his data without key-value pairing and I assumed he doesn't require it.

Answer (score 0):

In jQuery, you have to know when the DOM is ready to execute any code, because, jQuery is about the DOM manipulation and you can't manipulate html tags when doesn't exist in the DOM.

You can use:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    // Code...
});
```

Or

```
$(function()
{
    // Code...
});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() { // This code makes sure to execute Javascript code when the DOM is loaded completely, only once.
  alert("Here #1");

  $("#buttonClick").click(function() {
    var div = $("#mainBackground");
    div.slideUp(400, function() {
      redirect();

    });
  });

  alert("Here #2");

  $("#sign").click(function() {
    jQuery.ajax({
      url: "check_availability.php",
      data: { // Correct
        username: $("#username").val(),
        password: $("#password").val()
      },
      type: "POST",
      success: function(data) {
        alert("hereagain");
        if ($("#username").val() === "") {
          //Do nothing
        } else if ($('#username').val().length < 5) {
          $("#usernameConsole").html("Username must be 5-15 characters");
          $("#username").css('backgroundColor', '#ff6666');
          $("#usernameAvailable").css('color', '#ff6666');
        } else if (data === "accept") {
          $("#usernameConsole").html("Signed In");
          $("#username").css('backgroundColor', '#66cc66');
          $("#usernameAvailable").css('color', '#66cc66');
        } else {
          $("#usernameConsole").html("Not accepted");
          $("#username").css('backgroundColor', '#ff6666');
          $("#usernameAvailable").css('color', '#ff6666');
        }
      },
      error: function() {}
    });
  });
});
```